# Ansible playbook to check a file in the particular location until the file has been created by a process/manually

Tags: ansible

The real scenario is,

I have to keep on check a particular location to check a file(created by another service) is exist or not until I stopping the ansible-playbook script manually.

but the script has to check all the hosts until I stopping the script. also, it has to print the message that either file exists or not continuously for each host.

I tried to write the playbook by using the below code which checks file location only one time(obviously).

```
  tasks:
- name: checking the flag in /path/to/file directory.
  stat:
    path: /path/to/the/file
  register: file_name
- name: Report if file exists
  debug:
    msg: 'Exception occured {{ inventory_hostname }}'
  when: file_name.stat.exists
- name: Report if file not exists
  debug:
    msg: 'ATF still running {{ inventory_hostname }}'
  when: not file_name.stat.exists
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use until to check for the status of the file:

```
- name: checking the flag in /home/dev/ATF/ directory.
  stat:
    path: /path/to/the/file
  register: file_name
  until: file_name.stat.exists is not false
  retries: 10
  delay: 5
```

Comment: ansible execution flow goes one after another host as per the host list. that is, only when host1 satisfies the until condition ansible execution goes and checks the host2. so until execution comes to hostn, we never know that the expected file is present in the location or not.

Comment: Si if I understand well you want to check if the file is there on host1 when everything else completed, am I right ?

Comment: No @Cyrille, it's something about my requirement. The above comment is not relatable and kindly ignore that. Thanks for your help.